# PHP Timeout when connecting to nexus.passport.com

Tags: php, timeout, msn

I'm writing an MSN client in PHP. This is my code for so far:

```
$socket = fsockopen("messenger.hotmail.com", 1863);
echo '<b>Connected to 1st server.</b><br />';
//Send MSNP version
fputs($socket, "VER 0 MSNP10 CVR0\r\n");
echo fread($socket, 5000) . '<br />';
//Send user-agent
fputs($socket, "CVR 1 0x0409 php ".phpversion()." i386 MSNMSGR 7.0.0000 MSMSGS ".$_POST["username"]."\r\n");
echo fread($socket, 5000) . '<br />';
//Send username
fputs($socket, "USR 2 TWN I ".$_POST["username"]."\r\n");
//Read XFR
$xfr = fread($socket, 5000);
echo $xfr . '<br />';
$xfr = explode(" ", $xfr);

//Connect to second server
$server2 = explode(":", $xfr[3]);
$socket = fsockopen($server2[0], (int)$server2[1]);
echo '<b>Connected to 2nd server.</b><br />';
//Send MSNP version
fputs($socket, "VER 0 MSNP10 CVR0\r\n");
echo fread($socket, 5000) . '<br />';
//Send user-agent
fputs($socket, "CVR 1 0x0409 php ".phpversion()." i386 MSNMSGR 7.0.0000 MSMSGS ".$_POST["username"]."\r\n");
echo fread($socket, 5000) . '<br />';
//Send username
fputs($socket, "USR 2 TWN I ".$_POST["username"]."\r\n");
//Read USR
$usr = fread($socket, 5000);
echo $usr . '<br />';
$usr = explode(" ", $usr);

//Connect to Nexus
$nexus = fsockopen("nexus.passport.com", 443);
$request_nexus = "GET /rdr/pprdr.asp HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request_nexus .= "Host:nexus.passport.com\r\n";
$request_nexus .= "User-Agent:MSNphp/1.0 (PHP; U; PHP 5; en-US)\r\n";
$request_nexus .= "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
$request_nexus .= "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n";
$request_nexus .= "Keep-Alive:300\r\n";
$request_nexus .= "Connection:keep-alive\r\n";
$request_nexus .= "Cache-Control:max-age=0\r\n\r\n";
fputs($nexus, $request_nexus);
echo fread($nexus, 5000);//This is line 54, which causes the error
```

My result is this:

```
Connected to 1st server.
VER 0 MSNP10
CVR 1 1.0.0000 1.0.0000 1.0.0000 http://msgr.dlservice.microsoft.com http://download.live.com/?sku=messenger
XFR 2 NS 207.46.124.241:1863 0 65.54.239.21:1863
Connected to 2nd server.
VER 0 MSNP10
CVR 1 1.0.0000 1.0.0000 1.0.0000 http://msgr.dlservice.microsoft.com http://download.live.com/?sku=messenger
USR 2 TWN S ct=1249043921,rver=5.5.4177.0,wp=FS_40SEC_0_COMPACT,lc=1033,id=507,ru=http:%2F%2Fmessenger.msn.com,tw=0,kpp=1,kv=4,ver=2.1.6000.1,rn=1lgjBfIL,tpf=b0735e3a873dfb5e75054465196398e0

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\msnphp\chat.php on line 54
```

I get a timeout error when I connect to Nexus. But when I make a request to https://nexus.passport.com/rdr/pprdr.asp in Firefox, I get the result I want (checked with HttpFox). Why does Nexus take so much to to respond to my script? In Firefox it takes 2 seconds.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst you are connecting to the SSL port (443) on nexus.passport.com , you aren't actually sending the information encrypted: therefore Nexus is just waiting for the encrypted data to arrive and eventually timing out (your PHP script is timing out before hand).

You'll probably be best using [Curl](http://php.net/curl) to send the information to nexus as it's able to handle the SSL connection for you (why reinvent the wheel?).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the SSL. I use ssl://nexus.passport.com as host now! Btw... I don't really like cURL. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your script is running to long. PHP has a mechanism where it kills a script if it runs longer then specified in settings. You can change this value (it's called `max_execution_time`) in your `php.ini` or you can use [set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function to alter it in your script.

Comment: mmm... I know this, but why does nexus take more than 30 secs to respond to my PHP script, but 2 secs to respond to Firefox?

Comment: Is your server running on the same computer as your firefox?